# Soapbox on a street corner

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, language

When I was walking today, I came across a man standing on a soapbox. He was broadcasting his view to the world, and though he was speaking in English, I couldn't understand what he was going on about. It sounded like he was reading out a random list of words Most people weren't paying him a shred of attention, but I've done my best to transcribe what he said - maybe you can make more sense out of it than me. He broke off every now and again to get his breath (it was a pretty rapid speech) so I've inserted a newline each time. At the end he was puffing and panting and stopped because he kept spluttering so some of the words might be less reliable

## How do you think he felt?

> The Anamib *(?)* cooperative few are different, bug hyperactive...
> Nervous 2015 desert brewed organisms found populations, bomb antifreeze...
> System study beetle care outside, in have Y-protein...
> In provided has is, high-men-opera *(said as one word, ?)* almost between our beetles
> Beetles for inspired also exhibit, every them next...
> Contains independent A, found this habitat developed terrorist...
> All estimates self-filling in behavior, except resistance attack...
> The of water the the the too could...
> Types total bottle best only C major on...
> Found number which beetles beetle and class' sick...
> In of utilises the, two the of legs...
> Insects beetle hydrophilic larvae so polar insecticide...
> Varying species and feed is regions...
> Between giving hydrophobic on the...
> Different A-materials the weevil...
> Species mean two semi-digested Aust-row-platypus *(?)*...
> From estimate benefit fee-sees in-comp-a-tus *(?)*...
> Free of living of...
> Thaw-a-sick *(?)* some in the...
> And 1.5 dry adults...
> 7 million regions...
> Or with with...
> 8 a no...
> Abominable surprisingly regular...
> G-angular *(?)* narrow rainfall...
> Which range...
> Can spanning...
> Be all...
> Distinguish for...
> To estimates...
> That from...
> In a...
> Which minimum...
> The of...
> Thaw-a-sick *(again)* 0.9...
> And 2...
> Abominable a...
> G-angular *(again)* maximum...
> Are of...
> Few's 2.1...
> 2 million...
> Form bee tool...
> A species...
> Composed...
> Rupture.

---

*(Hereon is not part of the puzzle, just some random notes)*

By this puzzle's nature, part of it may not always be accurate.

You might need to do some research.

<sup>This story is based on a fictional event and taken from there...</sup>

Part of an upcoming <kbd>[metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)</kbd>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Findings**

> The idea here is to take the first word of each line and make a sentence. Then, take second word of each line and make another and go on. Doing that you will see, everything is picked up from [Beetle Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle) with a few typos and wordplays.

So...

> **Taking first word of each line gives -**
>
>  *The Nervous System In Beetles Contains All The Types Found In Insects Varying Between Different Species From Free Thaw-a-sick And 7 Or 8 Abominable G-angular Which Can Be Distinguish To That In Which The Thaw-a-sick And Abominable G-angular Are Few's 2... Form A Composed...Rupture.*
>
>  **Taking second word of each line gives -**
>
>  *A 2015 study provided for independent estimates of total number of beetle species giving A mean estimate of some 1.5 million... with a surprisingly narrow range... spanning... all... for... estimates... from... a... minimum... of... 0.9... 2... a... maximum... of... 2.1... million...  bee tool... species...*
>
>  **Taking third word of each line gives -**
>
>  *namib desert beetle has inspired A, self-filling water bottle which utilises hydrophilic and hydrophobic materials two benefit living in dry regions with... no... regular... rainfall...*
>
>  **Taking fourth word of each line gives -**
>
>  *Cooperative brewed care is, also found in the best beetles the, larvae feed on the semi-digested fee-sees of... the... adults...*
>
>  **Taking fifth word of each line gives -**
>
>  *few organisms outside, high-men-opera exhibit, this behavior, the only beetle two so is the... weevil Aust-row-platypus in-comp-a-tus*
>
>  **Taking sixth word of each line gives -**
>
>  *are found in almost every habitat except the C and the polar regions...*
>
>  **Taking seventh word of each line gives -**
>
>  *different, populations, have between them developed resistance too major class' of insecticide...*
>
>  **Taking eighth word of each line gives -**
>
>  *bug bomb Y our next... terrorist... attack... could... on... sick... legs...*
>
>  **Taking ninth word of each line gives -**
>
>   *hyperactive... antifreeze... protein beetles*

**And...**

> **There are some words which look like typos which are marked by '?'  -**
>
>  Anamib - A Namib
>  high-men-opera - Hymenoptera
>  Thaw-a-sick - thoracic
>  G-angualar - ganglia
>  Aust-row-platypus - Austroplatypus
>  Brewed - brood
>
>  **Some other typos -**
>
>  Y - Why
>  sick - Six
>  C - sea
>  abominable - Abdominal
>
>  **Some combined/seperated words**
>
>  A-materials - A materials
>  bee tool - Beetle
>  Y-protein - Why Protein

Comment: also abominable for abdominal

Comment: I've edited the puzzle - it might be easier now.

Answer (score 4):

I think Techidiot has really done all the work here, but:

> When all the words are disentangled and aligned appropriately, we find that we have a bunch of quotations from the Wikipedia article "Beetle", with assorted mis-hearings ... and also some omitted words. Some of the omissions are Latin biological names (though some of those have survived). Here are the quotations with the other omissions boldfaced:
>  The nervous system in beetles contains all the types found in insects, varying between different species, from three thoracic and seven or eight abdominal ganglia which can be distinguished to that in which **all** the thoracic and abdominal ganglia are fused to form a composite structure.
>  A 2015 study provided four independent estimates of **the** total number of beetle species, giving a mean estimate of some 1.5 million with a "surprisingly narrow range"[11] spanning all four estimates from a minimum of 0.9 to a maximum of 2.1 million beetle species.
>  [Moisture harvesting behavior by the] Namib desert beetle (Stenocara gracilipes) has inspired a self-filling water bottle which utilises hydrophilic and hydrophobic materials to benefit **people** living in dry regions with no regular rainfall.
>  Cooperative brood care is also found in the bess beetles (Passalidae) **where** the larvae feed on the semi-digested faeces of the adults.
>  Few organisms outside Hymenoptera exhibit this behavior; the only beetle to **do** so is the weevil Austroplatypus incompertus.
>  **They** are found in almost every habitat except the sea and the polar regions.
>  Different populations have between them developed resistance to **all** major classes of insecticide.
>  "Bug bomb: Why our next terrorist attack could **come** on six legs"
>  "Hyperactive antifreeze protein **from** beetles"

This seems like an obvious reference to

> the refrain of the **Beatles** song *Eleanor Rigby*

but the careful reader will notice that it says

> "All the people, where do they all come from?" rather than "All the **lonely** people, where do they all come from?"

and I take it that the

> omitted omission,

namely the word

> LONELY,

is the answer to the boldfaced question. Poor chap.

[EDITED to add:] By way of full disclosure I should admit that

> in the first posted version of this answer I missed some of the omissions, so that it looked as is there were too many omitted omissions. Skeptical readers with access to the edit history can verify that I showed some doubt as to whether I had got them all, but in any case it was after boboquack's comment below confirming that I hadn't that I went through more carefully so as not to miss any.

Comment: Since Techidiot did do most of the work, as you said, do you mind if I give the tick to them?

Comment: The only thing i would object to is if you gave the tick to someone other than the person you think deserves it :-).